Pandas .loc returns series or float inconsistently
I'm writing some code, and having trouble with some unexpected behaviour when using .loc in a pandas DataFrame, depending on the length of the dataframe itself. Some guidance on what is going on and how to avoid generating inconsistent outputs would be appreciated.
First of all, I'm working with Python 3.11 and pandas version 2.2.2. The problem is, depending on the dataframe length, .loc will return a one-item series, or a float64 object. Below the replica with some dummy example I made up.
First, when considering a longer dataframe, with multiindex, returns Series with .loc
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'ix1': ['asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'asd', 'qwe', 'asd', 'asd', 'qwe', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'asd', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'asd', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'asd', 'asd', 'asd', 'bar', 'qwe', 'qwe', 'asd', 'qwe', 'asd'],
     'ix2': ['sdf', 'bar', 'rty', 'fgh', 'cvb', 'cvb', 'vbn', 'bnm', 'jkl', 'ewq', 'uio', 'uio', 'wer', 'dsa', 'vbn', 'cxz', 'sdf', 'iuo', 'bar', 'bvc', 'fgh', 'rty', 'gfd', 'cvb', 'wer', 'bnm', 'ewq', 'tre', 'uyt', 'jhg', 'foo', 'dsa', 'mnb', 'jkl', 'iuy', 'lkj'],
     'value': [float(i) for i in range(1, 37)]})

>>> df[['ix1', 'ix2', 'value']].set_index(['ix1', 'ix2']).loc[('bar', 'foo'), 'value']
# <input>:1: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
# ix1  ix2
# bar  foo   31.00
# Name: value, dtype: float64

returns PerformanceWarning since index is not sorted and Series with float64 value (undesired)
Shorter dataframe, same structure, same index, same line of code executed, returns float64 insted
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {'ix1': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
     'ix2': ['tyu', 'fgh', 'vbn', 'jkl', 'foo', 'asd', 'qwe', 'foo'],
     'value': [float(i) for i in range(1, 9)]})

>>> df[['ix1', 'ix2', 'value']].set_index(['ix1', 'ix2']).loc[('bar', 'foo'), 'value']
# np.float64(8.0)

Simply returns a float64 (as desired)
This is causing trouble later down in the code because I need floating numbers with which to perform some calculations, and I don't seem to find what should I do to generate consistent outputs.

You question is not fully clear, do you always want a float?

I think OP is pointing to the fact that similar code returns different outputs

I see. The second example doesn't have duplicated combinations in the index

fair point. pandas is handling duplicate and non duplicate indices differently.  It probably is in the docs

Your second example doesn't have duplicated combinations of ix1/ix2, which prevents the issue.
If you always want a float I'd use:
cols = ['ix1', 'ix2']
df.drop_duplicates(cols).set_index(cols)['value'].loc[('bar', 'foo')]

Output: 31.0

You are right, I will add a control beforehand, thanks a lot! - I will review the documentation to see if this is expected behaviour
